# Iterating through class properties and objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, class, iteration, javascript-objects

I'm working with an automated GUI testing software that we write scripts in JavaScript. We write classes for all of our windows in the software. In these classes, we have objects for the individual fields with properties like the object definition according to the IDE, the name of the field, min, max and default values, etc. I have functions to verify the contents of the fields and I'm working on a function to verify that all fields that should be present are there.

The IDE we use, does not actually have the class keyword included with it's javascript so we're using the function keyword to try and create a similar structure.

It all looks something like this:

```
function Window()
{
    Window.call(this) // We have a class for all windows that contains all of our basic interaction and verification functions.

    // Variables
    this.ob = main.WindowObject;
    this.name = "Window Name";
    this.primaryTab = [main.PrimaryTabObject];
    this.secondaryTab = [main.SecondaryTabObject];
    
    // Objects
    this.WindowObjects =
    {
        FIELD1_DROPDOWN:
        {
            sObject: main.Field1ComboBox,
            name: "Field 1:",
            enum: enums.Field1,
            type: this.dropdownType
        },
        FIELD2_TEXTBOX:
        {
            sObject: main.Field2TextBox,
            name: "Field 2:",
            type: this.textboxType
        },
        FIELD3_DROPDOWN:
        {
            sObject: primary.Field3ComboBox,
            name: "Field 3:",
            enum: enums.Field3,
            defaultValue: enums.Field3.properties[enums.Field3.DEFAULT].name,
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 10,
            makeVisible: this.primaryTab,
            type: this.dropdownType
        },
        FIELD3_TEXTBOX:
        {
            sObject: primary.Field3Edit,
            name: "Field 3:",
            enum: enums.Field3,
            defaultValue: enums.Field3.properties[enums.Field3.DEFAULT].name,
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 10,
            makeVisible: this.primaryTab,
            type: this.textboxType
        },
        WINDOW_LABEL:
        {
            sObject: main.WindowLabel,
            name: this.name + " Label",
            type: this.labelType
        }
    }
}
```

We have a function in our primary Window class called "verifyFieldExists()".

```
this.verifyTextBoxDoesExist = function(textbox)
{
    const logMessage = "Verify that " + textbox.name + " " + textbox.type + " exists in the " + this.name +
                        " window.";
    const result = object.exists(textbox.sObject);
    let resultMessage;
    
    result
        ? resultMessage = "The " + textbox.type + " exists."
        : resultMessage = "The " + textbox.type + " does not exist.";

    resultVP(logMessage, resultMessage, result); // This is a function for logging our results.
}
```

You can see how this function is designed to take in one of these class "sub-objects" as an argument. Our windows have often 50+ fields in them and even over 100 sometimes. I feel like I should be able to create a method inside the class that loops through these objects to input them into this function, but the ways I've found so far don't seem to fully work and I can't figure out how to put it all together.

The best way I've found so far would look like this:

```
for (let property in class.WindowObjects)
{
    class.verifyTextBoxDoesExist (`${property}: ${class.WindowObjects[property]}`);
}
```

Which gives a fairly useless error.

EDIT: I've done some more research and found that I should be able to use a structure like this:

```
Object.keys(class.WindowObjects).forEach(e => class.verifyTextBoxDoesExist(`${class.WindowObjects[e]}`));
```

This seems to return what I want, but it seems to be giving an error at a function inbuilt into our IDE. There may not be a good solution here.

Comment: This doesn’t appear to be JavaScript: the class syntax is not the ES6 class syntax; `.call` cannot be used on classes; `class.WindowObjects` is currently a syntax error. What is the “useless error”?

Comment: The IDE we're using is not strictly using ES6. We don't actually have access to the class keyword. We've tried to emulate the class structure using functions the best we can. I've replaced function with class here to try and simplify but I think I've made things more confusing. I'll edit accordingly.